# can i create a generic method in non-generic class with method parameters either string or int type in java? if yes , how?

Tags: java

for ex.

```
obj.anyMethod(stringValue);
obj.anyMethod(intValue);
```

I tried :

```
<T> long anyMethod(T value){
   
    body
 
}
```

but this will accept any type of parameter....

Comment: An `int` can't be used as a parameter for generics. Anyway, just use simple method overloading and handle the common parts of the methods some other way (hard to tell you how without knowing what the method actually does with its parameter).

Comment: do we need generics here at all? why not `long anyMethod(Object value)` or, probably better, `anyMethod(SomeType value)`?